# Is it good practice to make multiple operation on same resource in single web API

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a table where we have user information. We have a scenario, where if given user Id is not present, then load the user information. If the user ID is present, then delete and load the new user information.

I have web API operation for that table,
so should I call the APIs as below

1. GET (to check whether the User ID is present or not)
2. POST (Based on GET response - If User ID not present, load the new user information)
3. DELETE (Based on the GET response - if User ID present, delete the old user information, and call POST to load new user information).

or

Should I call only

1. POST (check user ID is present in the table. If present, delete and load the new info. If not, load the new info)

In both the case, the requirement is achieved. But want to know what is the best REST API practice should I follow for this scenario. Is there any other way we can achieve this requirement with REST API standard?

Comment: you should go for option 2, as you told it is one transaction so it has to be completed inside one API only.  and also making separate http call is not cheap specially if you are on an environment where you need to pay for each API call.

Comment: Actually, From your question, I think all the actions(check the data, do  judgment,delete data) are in the same endpoint, So i think you just need to send one request.

Comment: got it, Thanks. I will go with option 2 \ performing all the action in one request